# How to get user data after signin in google plus api?

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus

I use following code to sign up in a website using google plus.
Using following code, i successfully signin in the sytem,but then how to get user data or gplus id?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();

     function signinCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
            console.log(authResult);
            document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');

        } else {
            console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
     }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="body">
        <span id="signinButton">
            <span
                class="g-signin"
                data-callback="signinCallback"
                data-clientid="565656566-u*********.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
                data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Is this code working in IE 8? IE 8 throws error because data-scope is set to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can get user data using access token,just make ajax call and you are done.use following code to get user data after successful signin.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();

     function signinCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
            console.log(authResult);
            document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
             /* get google plus id */
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token="+access_token
            })
            .done(function( data ){
                console.log(data);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
     }
    </script>
```

If you are trying to get user email address then change ajax with following:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token="+access_token
        })
```

[see this link for more deatils about get user data using google plus api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/)